# How do I expose port to host's ephemeral port and bind it to localhost

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Docker compose quesion (any version is fine)

I need to expose port 60000 from a container to host's ephemeral (random) port and bind it to localhost only.

Syntax

```
ports: 
   - 60000
```

results in 0.0.0.0:32XXX port exposure.

Syntax `- "127.0.0.1:YYYY:60000"` requires me to set static host port (YYYY)

I know I can bind docker daemon to listen only on localhost, but that doesnt really work for me, as I need another containers to listen on 0.0.0.0

Comment: Have yoy try `127.0.0.1::60000` instead?

Comment: Yes. Syntax error

Comment: i think you can't expose just on localhost, but from the 3.2 version of docker-compose you can:
``` version: '3.7'
services:
  web:
    image: "redis"
    ports:
      - target: 80
        published: 8080
        protocol: tcp
        mode: host
```
if you remove "published" flag from the docker-compose you can expose on "0.0.0.0" a random port

Answer (score 0):

If the syntax you show doesn't work, then Docker Compose 3.7 can't do this (but it is probably a fairly straightforward GitHub pull request to add it).  (Also note that this syntax *is* documented in the [`docker run`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#expose-incoming-ports) documentation; it's just a parsing issue in Compose.)

The best workaround is probably going to be to pick a "public" port yourself.  If you're trying to adapt a workflow built around `docker run -p 127.0.0.1::60000` or even `docker run -P` that will be trickier.

The actual source code for Docker Compose is in the GitHub [`docker/compose`](https://github.com/docker/compose) repository.  That includes a [configuration schema](https://github.com/docker/compose/blob/1.24.1/compose/config/config_schema_v3.7.json#L208) for the `docker-compose.yml` file, and a [`ServicePort.parse`](https://github.com/docker/compose/blob/1.24.1/compose/config/types.py#L385) method to handle the contents of `ports:`.  It seems like the `parse` method for a string doesn't support a missing published port (I'm not sure why) and the schema doesn't allow an `external_ip:` option for the [long syntax](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#long-syntax-1).